# Is there a System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager method that registers scripts inside the <head> tag?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, clientscriptmanager

I know it's strictly OK to put `<script>` tags in the body, but in the interest of neatness I'd like to use `System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager` to register a script in the `<head>` of my page.  Is there a method to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases I usually add a ContentPlaceHolder in the  tag of my Master Page.

Alternately I've used a method (usually in a utility class or PageBase class) that puts the script string in a List and stores it in the ASP.Net Context like so:

```
            List<string> javaScriptUrls = new List<string>();

            url = url.ToLower();

            javaScriptUrls = Context.Items[JS_KEY] as List<string>;

            if (javaScriptUrls == null)
            {
                javaScriptUrls = new List<string>();

                javaScriptUrls.Add(url);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!javaScriptUrls.Contains(url))
                    javaScriptUrls.Add(url);
            }

            Context.Items[JS_KEY] = javaScriptUrls;
```

Then OnPreRender of the MasterPage, it reads this List from the Context and builds  tags in the header.

```
            List<string> _javaScript = Context.Items[JS_KEY] as List<string>;

            foreach (string js in _javaScript)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl script = new HtmlGenericControl();
                script.TagName = "script";
                script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
                if (js.StartsWith("~/"))
                    script.Attributes.Add("src", head.ResolveUrl(js));
                else
                    script.Attributes.Add("src", js);

                head.Controls.Add(script);

                AddHeaderLineBreak(head);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  This workaround means I can't use "IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered"... I suppose you could just keep adding the urls to the list and then only register the unique entries.

Comment: correct. Notice this line:

 if (!javaScriptUrls.Contains(url.ToLower()))
                    javaScriptUrls.Add(url);

That maintains uniqueness in the list