# Add multiple elements to a HtmlHead object from within a class

Tags: c#

I have a website with a bunch of pages.  I have 4 master pages that all of the pages use.  Each page uses different css and JavaScript includes inside of the head tags.  I would like to add the title, meta description, and meta keywords tags in through a call to a class that will reference a database table.  However, I cannot figure out a way to pass the page or an HthmlHead object into the class without it throwing an error.  I have tried doing

```
HtmlHead head = Page.Header;
Page.Controls.Remove(Page.FindControl("HeadElement"));
Page.FindControl("HtmlElement").Controls.AddAt(0,HeaderText.getHeaderText(head, Request.Url.AbsolutePath));
```

and

```
Page = p2
Page = HeaderText.getHeaderText(p2, Request.Url.AbsolutePath));
```

In both cases I changed my class HeaderText.getHeaderText to return the page or HtmlHead types depending on what I was doing.  I setup the class to look like this:

```
    public class HeaderText
    {
        private HeaderText() { }

        public static HtmlHead getHeaderText(HtmlHead head, String URL)
```

Is there a better or easier way to do this?

Comment: I answered a similar question. Let me know if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146092/is-there-a-system-web-ui-clientscriptmanager-method-that-registers-scripts-inside/2146871#2146871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of these two suggestions:

1) Make your Master Pages all have a HeadContentPlaceHolder which exists inside of a  tag that **does not** have a *runat="server"* attribute. Then you can manipulate those contents at your leisure.

```
<head>
    <link ....>
    <script....>
    <meta......>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="headContentPlaceHolder"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

You could also use the Page.Title to set the title easily from each Page

2) use the **MasterType** reference on each Content Pages

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="My.App.MasterPage" %>
```

So if you had a "SetHeaderElements" method in your Master page class, you could call them from each Content Page that had that MasterType defined

```
Page.Master.SetHeaderElements(meta, css, js);
```

You can also try to avoid having this code in each of your Content Pages by have a PageBase class which returns your Master Page like this

```
public class PageBase : Page
{
    public IMasterPage MasterPage { get { return Page.Master as IMasterPage; }}
}
```

Then create an IMasterPage interface with the SetHeaderElements() method and have each of your MasterPage classes implement this interface.